# How to reference a children method in a parent method in Python?

Tags: python

I want to define a parent class called "Dice" and a few children classes, that represent different kinds of dice (for example D6, D20, and so on).
Every Die has some common structure, for example you can roll every Die, but the rules that decide the output are different.

I want to define a method that rolls the die in the parent class Dice, so that I won't have to define roll for every children class, but it also needs to reference to the kind of dice defined in the children class.

This is the code snippet:

```
import numpy 

class Dice:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def roll(self):
       return self.result()

class D6(Dice):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
    def result(self):
        return numpy.random.randint(1, 6)
```

I would like to know if referencing to the children method "result" in the parent method "roll" is considered bad design or if I am good to go.
I know that one way to solve my doubt would be giving the number of faces as an input when instancing a new die, but in the future I would like to define more complex dice that follow more complex rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done using abstract methods.  You declare in `Dice` that every child class must implement a roll method.  The code would look like this:

Python will give an error if you try to call `Dice()` or if you try to create an instance of a subclass that doesn't define `result()`.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Dice(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def roll(self):
       return self.result()

    @abstractmethod
    def result(self): ...
```

Note that that ellipses at the end is literally an ellipses, not a placeholder for you to write something in.  Using `...` as the body of an abstract method is, by convention, the way of indicating "this isn't really the implementation."

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an abstract base class:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from random import randint


class Die(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abstractmethod
    def roll(self) -> int:
        ...


class D6(Die):
    def roll(self) -> int:
        return randint(1, 6)


dice = [D6("1d6") for _ in range(3)]
print(sum(d6.roll() for d6 in dice))  # prints the result of rolling 3d6
```

Since a common type of die is a polyhedral die, you could have another (non-abstract) class to represent that, where subclasses supply the number of faces when calling `super().__init__()`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from random import randint


class Die(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    @abstractmethod
    def roll(self) -> int:
        ...


class PolyhedralDie(Die):
    def __init__(self, name: str, faces: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.faces = faces

    def roll(self) -> int:
        return randint(1, self.faces)


class D6(PolyhedralDie):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, 6)


dice = [D6("1d6") for _ in range(3)]  
# could also say PolyhedralDie("1d6", 6) rather than D6("1d6")

print(sum(d6.roll() for d6 in dice))
```

Other hypothetical types of die (loaded dice?  non-Euclidean dice?) would inherit directly from `Die` and have to implement their own `roll`.